# How to draw glowing lines with glitter effect inside

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tutorial, line-art

I just wonder if there exists a tutorial for photoshop which I could follow to draw those shining lines especially with the glitter like effect on the right side. (you can see what I mean in this site: [example](http://www.psynai.com) Just click on the navigation to see different line effects / colors...)

From what I could see maybe I would need kind of a glitter brush set? Well, on the other hand I found a few but not describing what kind of blend modes needed to archive a similiar effect...

[image]

Comment: This tutorial ( http://www.denisdesigns.com/blog/2010/02/create-a-jumbotron-effect-in-photoshop/ ) might give you some ideas on one method to create such a pattern as you can see in the glitter.

Comment: Hi Blub, if you're looking for any tutorials, you should just google for them. This site isn't really intended for such questions (it's not a forum!). I think that's why two people downvoted your question. Good luck with it though! :)

Answer (score 1):

Open a new file on Photoshop, and put a black background.

[image]

Get the Pen Tool (P) with these settings:
[image]

And create your line the way you want.
[image]

I created a line and all lines that you create using the Pen Tool appear on the Path Palette (Window > Paths). Now that we have our line/work path we are going to create another layer, go to Brush Tool (B) and select an small brush (9 px soft round). Go to the Path Palette and right click the work path you have for the line you made, and select Stroke Path.

A new window will pop up, select Brush and check Simulate Pressure. This will make the brush that you have selected to go over the line that we have. If you have a bigger brush the line will be thicker and so on, whatever color you have selected will also be showing.

[image]

This will be the result:

[image]

Now select blending options or right click the layer and select blending options. check colour overlay and give the color you want to your line.
[image]

apply Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur

[image]

After that you should get this result.

[image]

Now that you know the basics, use your creativity to make your glow lines shine on your illustrations.

Answer (score 0):

This effect is created with the help of pen tool, you can create it manually but this will take lots of hard work.....there is some `shadow, inner shadow, outer glow and some more photoshop effects`

You can see some tutorials here :

- [abstract line and background](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/40-cool-abstract-and-background-photoshop-tutorials/)

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the shape with pen tool. Give it a color. For shininess, you need create some white layers with brush tool which has "overlay" blending mode and clip them into shape. For extra shininess, you can duplicate the white layer again.

For glitter effect, you need to create or find a pattern or texture image looking similar. When you get it, you can clip that, too and change the blend mode to "overlay" or "color dodge" until you get the effect you wanted.